# Centering a div with a background fixed and centered

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to get a div to center on a page with a background that is fixed and centered, but it adds horizontal and vertical scroll bars which move the div all over the page while keeping the background still. The background is exactly how I want it but I need the div to be centered and responsive.

[image]

CSS:

```
.landingImg{
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/VW2izVa.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 800px;

    min-width: 1560px;
    display: flex;
}
.jumbo{
    justify-content: center;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:10%;
    /* padding: 20px; */
    width: 475px;
    max-width: 475px;
    background:url("https://i.imgur.com/0XoMcjD.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;


}

.jumboContain{
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.call2Action{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.playBtn {
    margin: auto;
    background: #5a3c1c;
    border: none;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
 <div className="jumbo">
                    <div className="jumboContain">
                        <h1 className="display-4">KnightFall</h1>
                        <p className="lead">In a world where evil is left to thrive, a hero is needed to bring balance to the force! </p>
                        <hr className="my-4"></hr>
                        <p className="call2Action">Will you be that hero?</p>
                        <a className="playBtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/signup" role="button">Play Now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: A detail: Using `justify-content:` in a CSS rule (here: `.jumbo`) only makes sense / has any effect if you use `display: flex` in the same rule.

Comment: Apart from that, the `.landingImg` class for which you posted a CSS rule is not present in the HTML code you posted.

Comment: flexbox isn't working unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet which you can then adapt to your needs:

```css
.outer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    /* these 3 lines below do the magic */
    display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do like flexbox but unfortunately it is not working here. still giving the two scrolls

Comment: That's because the background or the image above it are too big, try to resize them